# How to add line numbers to BasicTextField in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, editor, textfield

I'm creating a code editor app in Jetpack Compose. I'm using a `BasicTextField` that fills the entire screen. Now, I want to show line numbers alongside the text field. However, the lines of the text field don't align with the line numbers vertically.

I saw some examples such as the [Code Viewer](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/tree/master/examples%2Fcodeviewer) example from Compose Multi-platform. However, since the example uses static text instead of a text field, the lines don't align when I use a `BasicTextField`.

I also tried using this code:

```
var lineTops by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyArray<Float>()) }
val density = LocalDensity.current

BasicTextField(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    onTextLayout = { result ->
        lineTops = Array(result.lineCount) { result.getLineTop(it) }
    },
    decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
        Row {
            if (lineTops.isNotEmpty()) {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 4.dp)) {
                    lineTops.forEachIndexed { index, top ->
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier.offset(y = with(density) { top.toDp() }),
                            text = index.toString()
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            innerTextField()
        }
    }
)
```

But, still the issue of alignment persists.

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: @wiiznokes3 No, still haven't been able to figure it out.